# What is my error log telling me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typhoeus

I am trying to resolve a problem with an 3rd party application I am integrating with. Our API access was IP blocked due to a series of errors being raised because of calls we were making to the 3rd party application. After chatting to them they sent me the error that they were receiving in their logs.

```
A sample request sent is: [REMOVED_IP] - [REMOVED_API_TOKEN] [18/Aug/2015:12:57:42 +0000] "PUT /contacts/5016104701.json HTTP/1.1" 500 38052 "-" "Typhoeus -https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus" "[REMOVED_IP]".
```

According to them

*It looks like the particular IP was hitting the url https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus several times. Also, we got multiple Nginx 500 Errors for that domain too.*

From my understanding the log they sent me is saying that there was an internal server error (500) on their side. I have am guessing that `"Typhoeus -https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus"` is a response header. From my research that could be the effective URL being returned in the response. Something to do with redirection, but I could not find much on it.

My questions are:

Is this an error on their side? I am guessing it's an error in their application.
What is the `"Typhoeus -https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus"` in the response header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems that the error is on their part.

`Typhoeus -https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus` is the default user agent.
https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/blob/master/lib/typhoeus.rb#L50